# Alternative to support vector machine classifier in python?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have to make comparison between 155 image feature vectors. Every feature vector has got  5 features.
My image are divided in 10 classes.
Unfortunately i need at least 100 images for class for using support vector machine , There is any alternative?

Comment: kNN is there, but may not be as good as SVM.

Comment: It uses an euclidean distance metric, mixing all values itdoesn't concern that there are different feaetures

Comment: With only 155 samples and 10 classes, any classifier you try isn't going to give you very optimistic results. But you can try ensembles like `RandomForestClassifier`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

15 samples per class is very low for any machine learning model. Rather than wasting time trying many model classes and parameters you should collect and label new examples by hand. It will be much more fruitful. If you have a bunch of unlabeled pictures, you can use services such as https://www.mturk.com/ .

Comment: mturk It's not free, maybe it's much easier find a metric, analyzing features by hand

Comment: If you only have 10 possible classes, an image classification task on mturk can probably find workers for just $0.01 an image making the annotation cost of 100 additional images (provided you have them in the first place) just $1. 

Off course you can still label pictures yourself directly. It will just take longer if you have thousands of them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out pybrain.http://pybrain.org. And possibly use neural net as I've heard they need less data to train than svm's but less accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If your images that belong to the same class are results of a transformations to some starting image you can increase your training size by making transofrmations to your labeled examples.

For example if you are doing character recognition, afine or elastic transforamtions can be used. P.Simard in  Best Practices for Convolutional Neural Networks Applied to Visual Document Analysis describes it in more detail. In the paper he uses Neural Networks but the same applies for SVM.